# Unity animations not transitioning properly

Tags: unity, 2d, animation

I am currently trying to animate transitions between four different directions. I have four total animations for walking, and another four for the idle state. I cannot seem to figure out why when I try to transition from a walking state to another walking state in a different direction (not the direction I am idling in) it must wait for the walking animation to finish, and then play the walking animation in the new direction.

[image: This is what it looks like]

You can see my sprite begin to walk forward, and then when I attempt to turn south the animation it continually plays the north animation until the animation is finished. What I am trying to achieve is a smooth transition that switches immediately.

I know very little about animating and much more about programming. My list of attempted solutions is very short, and limited to only changing the length of each animation.

Comment: Try changing the transition duration in the animator view.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found the transition duration in the inspector, and I changed it from 0.25 to 0 and I don't see any noticeable difference. I also tried turning off Fixed Duration with no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't have enough points to comment but have you tried turning of **Has Exit Time**

Comment: However, I still have noticed that it won't cut the animation off no matter what point it is at. Has Exit Time only applies to the time after the end of the transition, unfortunately.

Comment: It's funny because the answer was a combination of both of your suggestions. I just set the transition duration to 0 and now it is an instantaneous switch.